# How to advance cursor in multi spinbox input widget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, qspinbox

I made a widget to input a MAC address using 6 QSpinBox widgets in Qt Designer using this simple code to display numbers as HEX and accept HEX as input:

```
class HexSpinBox(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    def textFromValue(self, value):
        return "{0:02x}".format(value)

    def validate(self, text, pos):
        if text == "":
            return QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate
        try:
            value = int("0x" + text, 16)
        except ValueError:
            return QtGui.QValidator.Invalid
        if value < 0:
            return QtGui.QValidator.Invalid
        if value > 255:
            return QtGui.QValidator.Invalid
        return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable

    def valueFromText(self, text):
        return int("0x" + text, 16)

class MACWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        loadUi("client/qt/Networking/MACWidget.ui", self, {"HexSpinBox": HexSpinBox})
        # This gives me self.spinBox_1 through self.spinBox_6 of tpye HexSpinBox
```

Now I want to be able to select the first SpinBox out of the six and then type in the full 12 digit MAC. After entering 2 digits each I want the focus to jump to the next SpinBox and select the content so it can be overwritten by typing more.

How do I do that in QT4.8?

Comment: The real question is, though: why do you use 6 QSpinBox widgets? All you really care for is a text field that accepts a valid MAC, right? Why split it into 6 widgets? With separate widgets, it becomes very awkward to copy and paste data. Basically, you will need to make those widgets act like a text field: when you type, cursor jumps between them, when you copy - the entire MAC is copied, when you paste - the MAC elements are pasted into spinboxes. It's hard because you shouldn't be doing it. Use a `QTextEdit` with a validator, and provide visual feedback (red/yellow/green) for validity.

Comment: I use spin boxes so you can increment or decrement parts easily. The use case is for entering MACs for virtual machines where you have for example one byte prefix, one byte for the NIC (eth0=0, eth1=1, ...) and 4 bytes matching the IP.

Comment: It is much easier to trap up/down arrow presses, and scroll wheel if you so wish, with a `QLineEdit` and make it change the value than dealing with the spinbox mess. `QLineEdit` doesn't itself use the up/down arrows, so reusing them for something special seems like a valid approach.

Comment: The model for this would be QDateTimeEdit, where different parts of the value are incremented/decremented according to the position of the caret within the line-edit.